# How to change Popup menu background color

Tags: kotlin, styles, popupmenu

I've implemented a popup menu in my recyclerview adapter, but I have a problem with the popup menu background color.

[image]

As you can see the background makes the menu look unappealing. All I want to do is make the background white and leave the text color as it is.

I've tried other solutions, but they haven't worked for me.

**This is one of them**

```
  <style name="CustomPopUpStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

 holder.mMenu.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { //creating a popup menu
        val popup = PopupMenu(context, holder.mMenu, R.style.CustomPopUpStyle)
        //inflating menu from xml resource
        popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu)
```

These don't yield any results. My popup menu still looks the same as the above image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. It turns out all I had to do was change my main theme's item background.

```
    <style name="Theme.MyNotepad" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>

    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" >?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item> <!-- Made the change here -->
```